# iPhone Animation : How to animate only subview ? Not the whole view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I am new with animations and I am using following code for Flip animation.

```
//MyMapView is UIView

MyMapView *aMapView = [[MyMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 118, 321, 300) AndResArray:self.nearMeArray];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [[self view] addSubview:nearMeMap];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Its working fine. But whole view (with super view) Flips.

I only want to Flip subview that is `MyMapView`. The super view should not flip.

How to do this ???

**EDITED**

screen :

Below is main screen. When click on Map button I want to Flip only Brown part of the screen. Whole screen should not Flip.

[image]

Thanks...

Comment: You need to paste your views to animate into another subview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figure out what's the problem. Please see the below code.

MapView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code.

    [self performSelector:@selector(addMapView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

}
return self;
}

- (void) addMapView {

//MyMapView is UIView

MKMapView  *aMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 321, 300)];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self cache:YES];
[self addSubview:aMapView];

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

And after that simply add object of MapView class where you want. like below.

```
//MyMapView is UIView
mapView  *aMapView = [[mapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 118, 321, 300)];
[[self view] addSubview:aMapView];
```

vote up if this comment help you.

Thanks,

MinuMaster.

Comment: great code thanks.... one more thing when I animate it the background should get cleared. any idea?

Comment: super view background... and how to remove it with animation UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft ???

Comment: create one method in MapView class and remain same code but change line addSubView to the removeFromsuperView.

Answer (score 2):

Matteo's answer is partially correct, but you need to set the animation on the view before you add it, or it won't work correctly.  Like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                       forView:aMapView
                         cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:aMapView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Alternatively, you can use the block-based API introduced in iOS 4.  Here's an example.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:aMapView
        duration:1.0
        options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
        animations:^{ [self.view addSubview:aMapView]; }
        completion:^(BOOL f){ }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your view to self.view and then flip only aMapView:

```
MyMapView *aMapView = [[MyMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 118, 321, 300) AndResArray:self.nearMeArray];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[self.view addSubView:aMapView];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:aMapView cache:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I tried it before... nothing happens..just aMapView get displayed without any animation !!!

Comment: I think I did the same thing !

Comment: aMapView get displayed without any animation !

Answer (score 1):

Animated transitions like this animate the contents of a view. The system takes a snapshot of the contents at the beginning of the animation, another snapshot when you commit, and then animates between them. As you've seen with your original code, the entire view gets animated.

The simplest solution is probably just to introduce an intermediate view that's the size and position of where the map will go. Then animate *that* view as you add the map to it.

More info in the View Programming Guide's section on [Creating Animated Transitions Between Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1). Though the methods you're using have, in iOS 4, been superceded by new block-based versions.

Comment: Intermediate view that's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    OptionView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
    OptionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    OptionIsShow=false;

    MoveView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 70, 70)];
    [MoveView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:MoveView];

}

-(void)ViewOrHideOptionView
{

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];

        [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.MoveView cache:NO];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

        if(!OptionIsShow)
        {
            [self.MoveView addSubview:OptionView];
            OptionIsShow=true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self.OptionView removeFromSuperview];
            OptionIsShow=false;
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```